# grunt build removes d3.js and google fonts from application

Tags: d3.js, gruntjs

I've configured my Angular app with Yeoman, and have included many JS libraries like d3. The application works fine when I use *grunt serve* to see the app. But when I try to build it using *grunt build*, and open the generated index.html, the app breaks because it cannot find D3. If I manually include the *script* tag for loading D3 in final index.html, then it starts working, but that's not how it's supposed to work, right?

The *grunt build* also removes google Fonts which I've included in my app:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This *link* tag is missing from final index.html

My bower.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "index.html",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.2",
    "lodash": "~4.9",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "angular": "~1.5",
    "angular-route": "~1.5",
    "angular-animate": "~1.5",
    "angular-resource": "~1.5",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.5.7",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.5",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~1.3.1",
    "moment": "~2.12",
    "less.js": "~2.6",
    "font-awesome": "~4.5",
    "d3": "^3.5.17"
  }
}
```

I have not tested the issue with other libraries, as they might also be not working after the build. However, angular, bootstrap, font-awesome and LESS is working fine. This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I was using dom_munger task in gruntfile. It removed all script with data-concat="false".

D3 script was being removed because it specified data-concat="false".

The problem is fixed now.