# Why do grunt build removes google fonts from the index.html

Tags: html, css, npm, bootstrap-4, gruntjs

The grunt build also removes google Fonts which I've included in my app:

```
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt|Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>   
        <link href="dist/magnific-popup.css?v=0.9.8" rel="stylesheet" />
```

After Grunt build, all the google font links are removed from new index.html.
Please help me with a solution

Comment: Did you search? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693973/grunt-build-removes-d3-js-and-google-fonts-from-application?rq=1

Comment: yes i did. it doesnt answer about why google fonts were removed